# Reed-Solomon algorithm

Tags: c#, sql-server, reed-solomon

I have an application in C# with a SQL Server database. I receive some files in notepad and one column is encrypted with the Reed-Solomon algorithm.

Can somebody tell me how can I can use the Reed-Solomon algorithm to decode/correct errors in  some strings in SQL Server or C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Reed-Solomon isn't an encryption scheme. Are you sure you have the right term here?

Comment: I have to apply solomon reed to a number.I don't know exactly what this algoritm does.When I receive the documentation for the text files ,i had a notation that tell me than on a numeric field I should apply solomon reed algoritm

Comment: @Mat - A non-systematic BCH encode multiplies a message by the generator polynomial, so the original message does not appear in the encoded message. Without knowing the generator polynomial, decoding would be tricky. A non-systematic original view encode would output values from a set of data points using the message itself as the generating polynomial. Without knowing the set of data points, decoding would be tricky. [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) describes these encoding schemes.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking to implement Reed-solomon error correction themselves, this is the best resource I've found yet that explains it:

"BBC R&D White paper WHP-031 - Reed-solomon error correction" by C.K.P Clarke:

http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/whp/whp-pdf-files/WHP031.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Try using [ReedSolomonDecoder](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1530218) from ZXing project.

Incidentally, Reed-Solomon is a fault-tolerant encoding, not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Where I can find this ?I tried with using Utility but doesn't recogninize it .I tried also adding Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware.dll and then I added ' using microsoft.spot.hardware' but doesn't recognize also .

Comment: Sorry, that link was for SPOT, which is .NET for embedded devices. Use the source file in the edited link :)

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but since the OP mentioned encryption, I'm wondering if a non-systematic encoder was being used. A non-systematic BCH encoder multiplies a message by the generator polynomial, so the original message does not appear in the encoded message. Without knowing the generator polynomial, decoding would be difficult. A non-systematic original view encoder would generate values from a set of data points using the message itself as the generating polynomial. Without knowing the set of data points, decoding would be difficult.

Also if original view encoding is used, then the decoders are different than the ones used for BCH view encoding, and not covered in the links provided in the other answers here (as of this date). The wiki article contains descriptions and links for the most common decoders for both original and BCH view encoding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction